# GoogleApiClient and Drive.API error

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to enable Saved Game in my Android game. However, I find that if I call

```
builder.addApi(Drive.API);
builder.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER);
```

the "Select Account" dialog doesn't even shown at all, and I cannot therefore sign in.

Uncommenting both lines and everything works fine (sign in, leaderboard, achievement) except Save Game. Trying to get a Snapshot gives me the following error

```
01-11 23:30:14.549  18072-18488/? E/Evader﹕ Must include Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER to use snapshots!
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must include Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER to use snapshots!
```

Is this deprecated? This is the method recommended on https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames

I am working with LibGDX and the BaseGameUtils if that's relevant

Answer (score 1):

If the code you included in your question is accurate, the problem is in how you are calling the Builder class.

The client is constructed using a builder pattern, so you need to update the return value of the previous call when creating the builder instance, such as: (notice there is only one semi-colon).

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .build();
```

Comment: As long as i addApi(Drive.API), the "Select Account" dialog wouldn't show.

Comment: So if you just use the scopes scope_appfolder and scope_games it worked?

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't with the code whatsoever. It was the phone(test device).
I tested on another device and it worked flawlessly.
I updated uninstalled Google Play Store and Google Play Services updates, and re-installed them, and everything worked.

TLDR - Test on multiple devices. I'm not exactly sure why that happened on my device for my game only, but after performing the above, everything works.

Thanks Clayton Wilkinson